# Charges for Querying Metadata tables in INFORMATION_SCHEMA in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Does Bigquery charge for querying tables in **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** and also some other metadata tables like `__TABLES__` . I tried to look for this information in the document here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing but seems like there is not much information about this.

If this is chargable then whether call getTable method from java client is also chargable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` depends on the rate you are using. If you are using on-demand pricing. Views incur a minimum of 10 MB of data processing charges. You can see the price in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing).

With Flat rates views and tables consume your purchased BigQuery slots. You can see the price in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#flat_rate_pricing).

For using metadata `__TABLES__` BigQuery offers queries up to the first 1TB of query data processed per month for free. You can see this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing).

You are not charged for querying this commands:

- _TABLE_SUFFIX
- _PARTITIONDATE
- _PARTITIONTIME
- _FILE_NAME
- **PARTITIONS_SUMMARY**
- **TABLES_SUMMARY**

Comment: Thanks @Raul if i use getTable api of java client then will i be charged for that as well?

Comment: @Sachin Janani The same terms apply either by api or directly in bigquery.

Comment: @Sachin Janani If this answer helped you, you can upvote or accept the answer. This can help future users who are having the same issue.